# How to bind to Nancy model when path includes a parameter

Tags: c#, asp.net, rest, nancy

Let's say I wanted to have the following REST endpoint: `/projects/{id}/jobs` and be able to post to it to create a new job. Kind of like this:

```
public class ProjectsModule : NancyModule
{
    public ProjectsModule() : base("/projects")
    {
        Post["/{id}/jobs"] = parameters =>
            {
                 // easy enough
                 var projectId = p.Id;

                 // but how do I specify that job JSON will be in the body of request?
                 var job = this.Bind<Job>();
            }
    }
}
```

How can I tell Nancy where to find the project Id and where to find the stuff to bind to job model?

Answer (score -1):

I do not fully understand your questions. projectId and job are empty? How does your json look? And your Job model?

Comment: Probably because you should use comments to ask questions to the user. Answers are only for... well, answers :)